# Angle + 180 degrees geometry term

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, terminology

Is there a term for an angle $\theta$ and its partner $\theta + 180^\circ$?

For example, $\theta$ and $90^\circ - \theta$ are complementary.

The context is that I have a graph with nodes and edges that maps to the XY-plane, and I'd like to have terminology to describe the two directions in which each edge points.

Comment: $\theta$ and $180^\circ- \theta$ are called supplementary angles (that is they sum to 180 degrees). Summing to $2\theta + 180^\circ$ isn't special and probably doesn't have a name.

Comment: I think OP is asking specifically $\theta$ and $\theta+180^\circ$.

Comment: I don't recall a specific name for a pair like that, but if I had to call them something, it would probably be "opposite" or "opposing" angles.

Comment: @AndrewChin is correct.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Unfortunately "opposite" angle already has its own meaning.

Comment: "antipodal"? ${}$

Comment: As a pilot we call that the reciprocal heading.  i.e. the reciprocal of 310 degrees is 130 degrees.  This terminology is used in other forms of navigation.  But, I have never heard it used in a purely mathematical setting.

Comment: Thanks everyone.